# jspdf add new page on when text is full on first page

Tags: jspdf

I am using JSPDF to generate pdf files in our site. I have some content which can vary in length each time. How can I automatically adjust JsPdf parameters to add new page every time the content overflows on first page

Answer (score 2):

Hye,

it's a bit later and answer is not perfect but it does the job for me (in ES6):

```
private createNewPdf() {
    this.positionY = MARGIN_TOP; // margin top
    this.pdf = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'mm', lineHeight: 1 });
}

// convert mm to fontSize
private setTextHeight(this.textHeight) {
    let fontSize = this.textHeight * 4;
    this.pdf.setFontSize(fontSize);
 }

private addText(text) {
    this.setTextHeight(textHeight);
    if (this.positionY + textHeight > (this.pdf.internal.pages.height - MARGIN_BOTTOM)) {
       this.addPage();
    }
    this.pdf.text(MARGIN_LEFT, this.positionY + this.textHeight, text);
    this.positionY += textHeight;
}

private addPage() {
   this.pdf.addPage();
   this.positionY = MARGIN_TOP;
}
```

So after you just have to:

```
this.textHeight = 3; // mm
this.positionY = 0; // position of previous text
this.pdf = null;

this.createNewPdf();
this.addText('My first text');
this.addText('My second text');
...
```

And if there is more text than place, page will be automatically added with MARGIN_TOP (you have to define this)

Answer (score 0):

I have different solution. Since the above said answers were bit complicated to implement, you can use the jspdf-autotable.

```
npm install jspdf-autotable
```

Import this and add the following

```
  const doc = jsPDF({ orientation: 'p' });
  doc.autoTable({
  theme: 'plain',
  headStyles: { halign: 'center', fontSize: 18, fontStyle: 'bold' },
  head: [[docName]],
  body: [
    [docData],
  ],
});
return doc.save(`${docName}.pdf`);
```

};

Where head is the document header that I needed, and docData is the data to be added. It will generate pdf document with multiple pages automatically.